# Solution of electrical network where arbitrary initial conditions cannot be assigned

Tags: circuit-analysis, network

Please consider the circuit below:

[image]

I'm trying to figure out how to formulate and solve some differential equations for this circuit. If I assign a state vector of:

$$
\textbf{x} = [V_{C1} \ V_{C2} \ V_{C3} \ i_L]
$$

And apply KCL and KVL:

$$
i_S - i_L + i_{C3} - i_{R2} = 0
$$

$$
i_{C2} + i_{C3} - i_{R2} = 0
$$

$$
-i_L + i_{C1} + i_{C3} = 0
$$

$$
-V_{in} + V_L + V_{C1} = 0
$$

$$
V_{in} - V_{C2} - V_{C1} + V_{C3} = 0
$$

$$
-V_{in} + V_{C2} + V_{R2} = 0
$$

Then I run into an issue with the voltage/capacitor loop comprising $$ V_{in} \ V_{C1} \ V_{C2} \ V_{C3} $$ as I cannot arbitrarily assign an initial value to the voltage across *C3*. Therefore, if I reformulate the state vector to omit *C3*

$$
\textbf{x} = [V_{C1} \ V_{C2} \ i_L]
$$

and instead use solve for *C3* using the corresponding KVL equation

$$
V_{C3} = -V_{in} + V_{C2} + V_{C1}
$$

then the system of equations becomes

$$
i_S - i_L + i_{C3} - i_{R2} = 0
$$

$$
i_{C2} + i_{C3} - i_{R2} = 0
$$

$$
-i_L + i_{C1} + i_{C3} = 0
$$

$$
-V_{in} + V_L + V_{C1} = 0
$$

$$
-V_{in} + V_{C2} + V_{R2} = 0
$$

and finally

$$
\frac{dV_{C1}}{dt} = \frac{i_{C1}}{C_1} 
$$

$$
\frac{dV_{C2}}{dt} = \frac{i_{C2}}{C_2} 
$$

$$
\frac{di_{L}}{dt} = \frac{V_{L}}{L} 
$$

My problem is that to solve the system of 5 equations to generate the state vector derivatives requires the current through *C3*. The only way I can think of determining this value is the differentiate the KVL equation relating to *C3*

$$
\frac{d}{dt} [V_{in} - V_{C2} - V_{C1} + V_{C3} ] = \frac{dV_{in}}{dt} - \frac{i_{C2}}{C_2} - \frac{i_{C1}}{C_1} + \frac{i_{C3}}{C_3} = 0
$$

and therefore

$$
i_{C3} = C_3 [ -\frac{dV_{in}}{dt} + \frac{i_{C2}}{C_2} + \frac{i_{C1}}{C_1} ]
$$

which can be substituted into the 5 equations.

The reason that I doubt that this is the simplest and correct solution to solving this circuit is that it requires the derivate of *Vin*.

If I simulate this circuit on Spice, I seem to get an answer that's equivalent to placing a small resistor in series with *Vin*, which breaks the voltage/capacitor loop and allows for arbitrary assignment of initial capacitor voltages.

So I'm hoping that someone can confirm:

1. How should a set of differential equations be formulated for the above circuit? Does it always require that the derivative of *Vin* be known or have I made a mistake somewhere?
2. How does circuit simulators handle cases similar to the above where some of the network elements are linearly dependent on others (i.e. arbitrary initial conditions cannot be assigned)?

Any help on the above would be appreciated.

EDIT:

I've attached two plots that show the results of my solutions to the system of ODEs.

The first simulates the circuits as shown. The Voltage for C3 is calculated as

$$
V_{C3} = -V_{in} + V_{C2} + V_{C1}
$$

and is post-processed after the simulation is complete.

[image]

The second adds a small resistor in series with the input voltage source. The breaks the voltage/capacitor loop and allows all of the capacitor voltages to be included in the state vector.

[image]

If I simulate the circuit with SPICE, I get results very similar to the second plot (the one with the inserted series resistor).

Note that when I simulate without the series resistor, I assume that

$$
\frac{dV_{in}}{dt} = 0
$$

as it is a DC source. However, if I was computing the step response with a Laplace transform, would this actually be equal to a unit impulse at t=0?

Comment: Circuit simulators allow you to provide an initial voltage to capacitors.  For your purposes, why not just assign it a variable name?

Comment: The problem is that you cannot arbitrarily assign initial values to all of the capacitors as the KVL equation Vin -Vc2 - Vc1 + Vc3 = 0 must always hold. As Vin is an independent voltage source and C2 and C1 are assigned initial values, then Vc3 is determined by those values and cannot be assigned an arbitrary value.

Comment: Which SPICE simulator did you use?

Comment: I used LTSpice to simulate.

Comment: Right-click on your inductor to see the note about how ESR defaults to 1mohm. You can also force it to zero there. See if that changes anything.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @SteKulov. The simulation ran the same with the ESR forced to 0. But thinking about it, I would expect that since a series resistor there does not break the loop. I also tried it forcing the ESR of all components to 0 and the result was the same. I also think that LTSpice only allows you to specify the initial voltage at a given node (and not the initial capacitor voltage), which avoids in inconsistent initial condition problem. So perhaps a simulator is not bothered by topologies like this? My question about the ODE system remains though.

Comment: OK.  You mentioned a series resistor, and the only hidden one LTspice sneaks in there is the inductor ESR so I thought it was worth checking out.  LTspice also adds parallel resistors to ground sometimes.  You can disable that by setting `.options topologycheck=0`.  You can set initial voltages across capacitors by adding `ic=XXX` after the value.  For example, `10u ic=3` would be a 10uF capacitor with 3V across it.  You have to use the `uic` flag though which is the last checkbox in the `.tran` simulation dialog.

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions @SteKulov, that was useful. I did what you suggested with the ic=XXX for all the capacitors. Interestingly, all of the voltages seemed to start at zero and ramp up to their first transient value after perhaps 0.5ps (this includes the DC source of 1V). Perhaps I'm interpreting the results incorrectly, but it does look like perhaps the simulator has some kind of numerical tricks for t=0 to ease simulation complexity?

Comment: If you use `uic`, then it sets all the initial conditions you don’t manually define to zero. That’s probably what’s going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The development of the state equations in the OP seems correct. The questioner seems thrown off by the derivative of the input appearing in the equations.

Notice that there is no dc path from input to output. When this is the case, a derivative of the input will appear. Take the case of a high pass filter shown in Figure 1.

The differential equation is:
$$
R_1 C_1\frac{dv_{C1}}{dt}+v_{C1}=\frac{dv_{in}}{dt}
$$
Which as a state equation is:
$$
\dot{x}=-\frac{1}{R_1C_1}x+\frac{1}{R_1C_1}\dot{v}_{in}
$$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZxFbRm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The input derivative result does not mean that the derivative is taken befor the input is applied. It just means that the circuit will take the derivative for you. The input is applied as normal

The transfer function for the sinple high pass filter is:
$$
\frac{V_{C1}}{V_{in}}=\frac{s}{s+\frac{1}{R_1C_1}}\tag{Equ 1}
$$

Which can also be written as:
$$
\frac{V_{C1}}{sV_{in}}=\frac{1}{s+\frac{1}{R_1C_1}}\tag{Equ 2}
$$

> The reason that I doubt that this is the simplest and correct solution to solving this circuit is that it requires the derivate of Vin.

> How should a set of differential equations be formulated for the above circuit? Does it always require that the derivative of Vin be known or have I made a mistake somewhere?

Applying a step voltage to a high pass filter produces the same result as applying an impulse to a low pass filter.

The state equations represent what the system does to the input, not what is done to the input before application.

> I cannot arbitrarily assign an initial value to the voltage across C3.

This is indeed the case. The capacitive loop of ideal capacitors means that one of them is dependent on the other two. The orderof the systemis the number of **independent storage elements** Only two of the capacitors are independent. Sothe systemis third order. If you wish to assign initial values in a simulator, you can only assign to two of them (any two will work). During analysis assign tothe ones that are selected as state variables.

> How does circuit simulators handle cases similar to the above where some of the network elements are linearly dependent on others (i.e. arbitrary initial conditions cannot be assigned)?

Initial conditions are not assigned to dependent variables.

---

The edit does not assist in answering the question. The system in the oroginalpost will not pass a constant (dc) value. The step will appear as a decaying exponential, oscillating or otherwise, to zero.

---

I am including the state equations and transferfunction I calculated for reference.

$$
\dot{x}_{1}=\frac{C_{3}}{R_{2}C_{123}}x_{2}+\frac{C_{2}+C_{3}}{C_{123}}x_{3}+\frac{C_{2}C_{3}}{C_{123}}\dot{v}_{in}-\frac{C_{3}}{R_{2}C_{123}}v_{in}
$$
$$
\dot{x}_{2}=-\frac{C_{1}+C_{3}}{R_{2}C_{123}}x_{2}-\frac{C_{3}}{C_{123}}x_{3}+\frac{C_{1}C_{3}}{C_{123}}\dot{v}_{in}+\frac{C_{1}+C_{3}}{R_{2}C_{123}}v_{in}
$$
$$
\dot{x}_{3}=-\frac{1}{L}x_{1}+\frac{1}{L}v_{in}
$$
$$
v_{out}=v_{3}=-x_{2}+v_{in}
$$
$$
C_{123}=\left(C_{1}C_{2}+C_{1}C_{3}+C_{3}C_{2}\right)
$$

TF
$$
\frac{V_{3}(s)}{V_{in}(s)}=\frac{s\left[\left(C_{3}+C_{2}\right)R_{2}+\left(C_{1}+C_{3}\right)LR_{2}C_{2}s^{2}\right]}{\left(1+\left(C_{1}+C_{3}\right)Ls^{2}\right)\left(1+R_{2}C_{2}s\right)}
$$

$$
\frac{V_{3}(s)}{sV_{in}(s)}=\frac{\left[\left(C_{3}+C_{2}\right)R_{2}+\left(C_{1}+C_{3}\right)LR_{2}C_{2}s^{2}\right]}{\left(1+\left(C_{1}+C_{3}\right)Ls^{2}\right)\left(1+R_{2}C_{2}s\right)}
$$

Comment: Hi @RusselH. Thanks for taking the time to reply. This I believe answers my question and your answers make sense to me. The only point you make that I don't understand is _"The step will appear as a decaying exponential, oscillating or otherwise, to zero."_ I think it looks like all capacitor voltages will settle at 1V, so it seems like the circuit will pass a DC voltage (if VC3 is taken as the output)? I simulated your equations and I get the same result as I do with the equations I generated.

Comment: Indeed the capacitor voltages do settle to 1 volt. But not all are the same polarity as in the diagram.. The output voltage v0=vin-vC2=0V=-vC3+vC1. So my statement that a dc voltage cannot pass is true from input to output as the transfer function indicates.

Comment: Picking this up again after more thought - how would I convert such a system into a state space representation? That does not permit derivatives of the input, but I've read a few examples that shows how to eliminate this by combining the variable into one of the state variables. However, in this case it would mean that I'd essentially need to modify the circuit I think (by merging 2 capacitors into 1 or something). But that does not seem physically possible to me.

Comment: @AndrewLees I believe that any system representable by linear ordinary differential equations is representable in state space form. So I think if you can get it into Laplace form then that's all you need to show it can be done in some state space form. That's not proof. Just my belief at this time.

Answer (score 1):

My previous study in A3 format(now deleted) in A4 page format (print page by page of a pdf file):

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi @Franc. Thanks for taking the time to reply. I understand how you generate your equations and system derivatives. If I am correct though, one of the capacitor voltage derivatives should be equal to the sum of the other two, plus the derivative of the input. I will try and determine if that is the case or not.

Answer (score 1):

Applying the Laplace transformation on your components along with their associated initial conditions yields this circuit: -

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGuojc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Using nodal analysis one gets \$V_2\$ to be this big expression: -

$$V_2 = \underbrace{V_\text{in} \cdot \frac{C_2C_3LR_2s^3 + (C_2R_2s + C_3R_2)s + 1}{(C_1C_2LR_2+C_1C_3LR_2+C_2C_3LR_2)s^3 + (C_1L+C_3L)s^2 + (C_2R_2+C_3R_2)s+1}}_\text{Zero-state response} + 
\underbrace{\frac{C_1C_2LR_2V_{C1}(0)s^2 + C_1C_3LR_2V_{C1}(0)s^2 - C_2C_3LR_2V_{C2}(0)s^2 + C_2C_3LR_2V_{C3}(0)s^2 + C_2I_L(0)LR_2s + C_3I_L(0)LR_2s + C_1LV_{C1}(0)s + C_3LV_{C3}(0)s + I_L(0)L}{(C_1C_2LR_2+C_1C_3LR_2+C_2C_3LR_2)s^3 + (C_1L+C_3L)s^2 + (C_2R_2+C_3R_2)s+1}}_\text{Zero-input response}$$

From this expression you can compute both the zero-state response and the zero-input response. The zero-state response is the system's response to the input when all initial conditions are set to zero ("zero-state"). The zero-input response is the system's response to its own initial conditions when the input is zero ("zero-input"). Notice also that the two fractions have the same denominator.

Lastly, the number of energy storing components is not generally equal to the system order. In this case, there are four energy storing components, but the system \$\frac{V_2}{V_\text{in}} \$ is only of third order.

The Maple code I used is here: -

```
restart;
ZL:=s*L:;ZC1:=1/(s*C1):;ZC2:=1/(s*C2):;ZC3:=1/(s*C3):;

sys:={(V2-Vin)/ZL-IL0/s+V2/ZC1-C1*VC10+(V2-V3)/ZC3-C3*VC30=0, V3/R2+(V3-Vin)/ZC2+C2*VC20+(V3-V2)/ZC3+C3*VC30=0}:
solutions:=solve(sys,{V2,V3}):
assign(solutions):
collect(V2,Vin):

lprint(%)
(C2*C3*L*R2*s^3+C2*R2*s+C3*R2*s+1)/(C1*C2*L*R2*s^3+C1*C3*L*R2*s^3+C2*C3*L*R2*s^
3+C1*L*s^2+C3*L*s^2+C2*R2*s+C3*R2*s+1)*Vin+(C1*C2*L*R2*VC10*s^2+C1*C3*L*R2*VC10
*s^2-C2*C3*L*R2*VC20*s^2+C2*C3*L*R2*VC30*s^2+C2*IL0*L*R2*s+C3*IL0*L*R2*s+C1*L*
VC10*s+C3*L*VC30*s+IL0*L)/(C1*C2*L*R2*s^3+C1*C3*L*R2*s^3+C2*C3*L*R2*s^3+C1*L*s^
2+C3*L*s^2+C2*R2*s+C3*R2*s+1)
```

Making a simulation in LTspice and MATLAB seems to yield the same result: -

[image]

[image]

```
>> s = tf('s');
>>C1 = 1e-6;
>> C2 = 1e-6;
>> C3 = 1e-9;
>> L1 = 1e-6;
>> R2 = 10;
>> H = (C2*C3*L*R2*s^3+C2*R2*s+C3*R2*s+1)/(C1*C2*L*R2*s^3+C1*C3*L*R2*s^3+C2*C3*L*R2*s^3+C1*L*s^2+C3*L*s^2+C2*R2*s+C3*R2*s+1)

H =
 
            1e-20 s^3 + 1.001e-05 s + 1
  -----------------------------------------------
  1.002e-17 s^3 + 1.001e-12 s^2 + 1.001e-05 s + 1
 
Continuous-time transfer function.
>> bode(H)
>> grid on
```

Comment: Hi @Carl, thank you for taking the time to answer. You mentioned in your answer that the number of energy storing components is not generally equal to the system order. Can you elaborate in what cases that is true? Does this occur when there is linear dependence amongst the energy storing components, as is the case in this example? Also, would you be able to compute the step response of your system and post the results so that I can compare with mine? It's also still not clear to me how you can set all initial capacitor voltages to zero and not violate a KVL equation.

Comment: @AndrewLees One example would be when there are two inductors in series and another when there are two capacitors in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we have the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9xU6c.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_0&=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_3\\
\\
\text{I}_1&=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_4\\
\\
\text{I}_5&=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_3\\
\\
\text{I}_0&=\text{I}_4+\text{I}_5
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_1&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_2}{\displaystyle\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_4&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_1-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\text{I}_5&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_2-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_5}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Substitute \$(2)\$ into \$(1)\$, in order to get:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_0&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_2}{\displaystyle\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_1-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_2-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_5}&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_2}{\displaystyle\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_0&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_1-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_4}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_2-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_5}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Now, let's solve for \$\displaystyle\text{V}_2\$:

$$\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_2}{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}}=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_5\left(\text{R}_1\text{R}_2+\text{R}_4\left(\text{R}_1+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)\right)}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1\text{R}_3\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_4\right)+\text{R}_1\text{R}_5\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)+\text{R}_2\text{R}_4\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_5\right)+\text{R}_3\text{R}_4\text{R}_5}\tag4$$

Applying this to your circuit we see that, using [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform):

- $$\text{R}_1=\text{sL}\tag5$$
- $$\text{R}_2=\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{sC}_1}\tag6$$
- $$\text{R}_3=\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{sC}_2}\tag7$$
- $$\text{R}_4=\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{sC}_3}\tag8$$

So, we get:

$$\frac{\displaystyle\text{v}_2\left(\text{s}\right)}{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)}=\frac{\displaystyle\text{R}_5\text{s}\left(\text{C}_1+\text{C}_2\left(1+\text{Ls}^2\left(\text{C}_1+\text{C}_3\right)\right)\right)}{\displaystyle1+\text{R}_5\text{s}\left(\text{C}_1+\text{C}_2\right)+\text{Ls}^2\left(\text{C}_1+\text{C}_3\right)+\text{LR}_5\text{s}^3\left(\text{C}_2\text{C}_3+\text{C}_1\left(\text{C}_2+\text{C}_3\right)\right)}\tag9$$

Comment: Hi @JanEerland, thanks for taking the time to answer. If I'm honest, I don't know if your reply answers my question or not. If I recall LTI systems correctly from university, a circuit with 3 capacitors and 1 inductor would be a 4th order system. So the Laplace transform should include s^4 terms? Your transfer function is only a 3rd order system I believe. Also, can you calculate and plot the step response of the function? I can compare that with my answer. Finally, how about the question of initial state and dealing with the capacitors?

Comment: The degree of the equation ... should ... be the number of "imaginary" components ... at max.