# State Space Formulation When the Equations Require Derivative of Input

Tags: circuit-analysis, state-space

Please see my related question here:
[Solution of electrical network where arbitrary initial conditions cannot be assigned](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/682634/solution-of-electrical-network-where-arbitrary-initial-conditions-cannot-be-assi)

Please consider that circuit.

I now understand that derivatives of the input are unavoidable here. I have a follow up question, that is:

Can that circuit be expressed in state space representation:

$$ \begin{eqnarray}
\dot{x} = Ax + Bu \\
y = Cx + Du
\end{eqnarray} $$

I does not obviously translate because of $$\frac{dV_{IN}}{dt}$$

but I am wondering if there's still a way of encoding this, perhaps by adding some additonal variable into the state-space?